# Return the number of directories

Tags: linux

I have this piped a command that tells me how many directories are inside the current directory:

`ls -lR | grep ^d | wc -l`

But is there a way to check for a given directory? Something like:

`ls -lR | grep ^d | wc -l /folder1/`?

Answer (score 1):

I think your just passing `/folder1` to the wrong cmd

`ls -lR /folder1 | grep ^d | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `find`. With `-type d` you can tell find to search only for directories. Like so

```
find /folder1 -type d | wc -l
```

The advantage is that you can easily change this to retrieve the names of the directories and also act on them with `-exec`.

The drawback is that this command also counts the directory `/folder` or `./`, but that's easily circumvented:

```
find /folder1 -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```